# npm install npm err exit status 8

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs, teamcity, npm-install

Getting the following error while builing project in teamcity on a build agent. This was working two days back on the same agent and giving the following error now. Please help.

I have updated the full log here if that helps. This is failing for a build in teamcity to which i am new. I am providing support for the application but still learning how to debug these issues. Any help would be appreciated, even in layman terms. Thanks guys.

```
 Step 1/5: install dependencies (Node.js NPM) (12s) 
    [Step 1/5] npm install (12s) 
[npm install] Executing npm via wrapping shell script
[npm install] Starting: /opt/home/teamcity/BuildAgent2/temp/agentTmp/wrapper3833224454633074147.sh install
[npm install] in directory: /opt/home/teamcity/BuildAgent2/work/cd110a4ceada3f8c
 [npm install] npm WARN package.json Adidas_ESS@0.1.0 No repository field.
 [npm install] npm WARN engine hoek@2.16.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.38","npm":"1.4.28"})
 [npm install] npm WARN engine cryptiles@2.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.38","npm":"1.4.28"})
 [npm install] npm WARN engine boom@2.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.38","npm":"1.4.28"})
 [npm install]
 [npm install] > phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 install /opt/home/teamcity/BuildAgent2/work/cd110a4ceada3f8c/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
[npm install] > node install.js
[npm install] 
[npm install] 
[npm install] module.js:340
[npm install]     throw err;
[npm install]           ^
[npm install] Error: Cannot find module '/opt/home/teamcity/BuildAgent2/work/cd110a4ceada3f8c/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js'
[npm install]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
[npm install]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
[npm install]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
[npm install]     at startup (node.js:119:16)
[npm install]     at node.js:935:3
[npm install] npm WARN engine hoek@2.16.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.38","npm":"1.4.28"})
[npm install] npm WARN engine cryptiles@2.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.38","npm":"1.4.28"})
[npm install] npm WARN engine boom@2.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"0.10.38","npm":"1.4.28"})
[npm install] 
[npm install] > phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 install /opt/home/teamcity/BuildAgent2/work/cd110a4ceada3f8c/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
[npm install] > node install.js
[npm install] 
[npm install] 
[npm install] module.js:340
[npm install]     throw err;
[npm install]           ^
[npm install] Error: Cannot find module '/opt/home/teamcity/BuildAgent2/work/cd110a4ceada3f8c/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js'
[npm install]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
[npm install]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
[npm install]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10
[npm install]     at startup (node.js:119:16)
[npm install]     at node.js:935:3 
[npm install]  

[npm install] npm ERR! phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 install: `node install.js` 
    [npm install] npm ERR! Exit status 8 
    [npm install] npm ERR! 
    [npm install] npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 install script. 
    [npm install] npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs-prebuilt package, 
    [npm install] npm ERR! not with npm itself. 
    [npm install] npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: 
    [npm install] npm ERR! node install.js 
    [npm install] npm ERR! You can get their info via: 
    [npm install] npm ERR! npm owner ls phantomjs-prebuilt 
    [npm install] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above. 
    [npm install] npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-409.el5 
    [npm install] npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" 
    [npm install] npm ERR! cwd /opt/home/teamcity/BuildAgent2/work/cd110a4ceada3f8c 
    [npm install] npm ERR! node -v v0.10.38 
    [npm install] npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28 
    [npm install] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
    [npm install] npm ERR! not ok code 0 
    [Step 1/5] Step install dependencies (Node.js NPM) failed
```

Comment: try `npm install --verbose` to get more output. Most likely it is about phantomjs postinstall script

Comment: maybe change the version number of phantomjs in the build-dependencies from "*" to a previous one

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's trying to install the latest package, and that is broken. Edit your package.json and find the version of PhantomJS. It will look like this:

```
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7"
```

Take out the "^" in front of it to install the version exactly specified. Your build is failing because it's trying to install a newer version of the package specified, and that package is broke. The "^" tell is to install at least that specified version, but get the latest one available.

Comment: Hi @boyan

I am very new to this as we provide support and build is failing for someone else on teamcity on a particular agent but working on other agents. I have to fix this for the user. Is there any way for that?

Comment: If your build is working on other agents but not on one agent, then that's an issue with that agent, or it could be an issue with your package.json file. Can you please update your question to provide the package.json?